# Only allow letters in textbox for MS Access

Tags: validation, ms-access, vba

I have a text box in a form in MS Access. I just want users to enter Letters and spaces. No special characters.

I have implemented the following on `KeyPress` Event. I am wondering is there any better way to implement the same.

```
Private Sub txtName_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
If KeyAscii <> 8 And KeyAscii <> 32 Then  'Not Backspace (important for error correction) and not a Space
    If (KeyAscii < 65 Or KeyAscii > 90) And (KeyAscii < 97 Or KeyAscii > 122) Then   'Allowing lower and upper case
    Beep 'Let the user know they hit an illegal key
    KeyAscii = 0 'Don't let the keystroke through
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Visual Basic KeyAscii Values - http://thecodeforyou.blogspot.in/2013/01/vb-keyascii-values.html

Comment: You'll need an afterupdate check as well to catch a wrongly copy-paste.

Comment: @Gustav, I believe BeforeUpdate event is the validation checker as you can cancel the update.

Comment: Yes, if that's what you want ... I would just clean the input.

Comment: Merging @Parfait and _Andre_ answers will provide you with the very best solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using the [BeforeUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845199.aspx) event of the textbox which is the trigger usually used to validate entry as you have the facility to cancel the update:

```
Private Sub txtWordsOnly_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If Me.txtWordsOnly Like "*[0-9]*" Or Me.txtWordsOnly Like "*[@#$%*^&?()<>/\'""!]*" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid entry. Please select only words," _
                 & " NOT numbers or special characters.", vbInformation
        Cancel = -1     ' OR Cancel = True
        Me.txtWordsOnly.Undo
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a validation rule.

Allen Browne has a highly useful list of Validation rules here:
http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html

### Letters and spaces only

```
Is Null Or Not Like "*[!a-z OR "" ""]*"
```

Punctuation and digits rejected.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I am using this text box to search. When user key's in the Name, the list bellow is updated. Hence validation might not work. As Validation will generate message box. Thus hampering the User Experience.